# Can a VPN be set on the personal hotspot in iOS 9.3?

Tags: ios, ipad, vpn

We're looking at deploying iPads using Apple Configurator, but one concern is the Personal Hotspot. We tried to hide the Settings app so it couldn't be turned on, but it doesn't look like that's possible in iOS 9.3 with Apple Configurator 2.2. As an alternative, is it possible to force all traffic from the Personal Hotspot to go over a VPN? The iPad will be in the supervised mode.

Comment: I'm not sure about using a VPN, but I believe you can have the carrier disable the hotspot. I know that I have the Personal Hotspot on my iPhone and my mother does not, despite using the same carrier. She did not add it onto her plan.

Comment: We're on a corporate account with an iPad Pro. Tried to have Verizon block it, but was told that they can't on any device after the iPad 4.

Comment: When you sign up for a new account with Verizon, you pick a plan. For the sake of discussion, let's say it's 5Gb/mo. When you sign up, they should ask you if you want to add on Personal Hotspot. It's a whole different fee. Once it's on there, it's on there and they can't disable it. But if you go into a new contract saying "I don't want Personal Hotspot," they should be able to exclude it. I just confirmed this with a Sprint Store Manager who used to work for AT&T. He said this is consistent across all carriers. There's a chance Verizon is different, of course!

Comment: @TMHahn - Verizon (and Sprint, and I think AT&T and T-Mobile (haven't verified recently)) haven't charged extra for the personal hotspot feature in quite some time